# Better method to Unpacks this Nested Dictionary?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, nested

I got a nested dictionary as follows and it will return the third key while inputting the first key in the dictionary

```
tree = {"Luke" : {"Darth Vader" : {"The Chancellor"}},
        "Neal" : {"Les" : {"Joseph"}},
        "George" : {"Fred" : {"Mickey"}},
        "Robert" : {"Tim" : {"Michael"}},
        "Juan" : {"Hunter" : {"Thompson"}}}



check_con = input("Enter your Name")
for fi_name,fi_second in tree.items():
    if check_con in fi_name:
        for fi_third,fi_fourth in fi_second.items():
            print(fi_fourth)
```

I feel that its bit more steps, is there any other way to do it?

Regard

Comment: You mean if you give "Luke" you want to return "The Chancellor" ?

Comment: @VikasDamodar , yes

Comment: Use `fi_second = tree[check_con]`. Or `fi_second = tree.get(check_con)` if it's not guaranteed that `check_con` exists.

Comment: I used the dictionary to make it simple,even if its possible with a single tuple,or list is okay for me

Comment: `.get(key[, default])` might be helpful here.

Comment: `list(tree[input()].values())`, it will return list of values in last set.

Comment: @VikasDamodar , can i have the full code

Comment: @VikasDamodar , yeah, that seems simple . good one

Comment: @Karamzov I think Sunitha's answer is a good one, it will also return none if key error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `dict.get` method with a default value of empty dict to get the top level dict and then convert its values to a iter, use `next` to get the first value

```
>>> check_con = 'Neal'
>>> next(iter(tree.get(check_con, {}).values()), '')
{'Joseph'}
>>> 
>>> check_con = 'xxx'
>>> next(iter(tree.get(check_con, {}).values()), '')
''
>>>
```

Comment: iter and next seems reduntant as this can be achived by `print((tree[check_con].keys()))`  ,

Comment: @Karamzov. In python2, they are redundant. You can instead use dict.keys()[0]. But on python3, they are needed to get the first element from the dict.keys().

Comment: in my dictionary format,is the last entry is a dict key or a set ?

Comment: @Karamzov. The inner most entry in your dict is a set. You can check it up using `type` command. `type({"The Chancellor"})` would give `<class 'set'>`

Comment: `type({"The Chancellor"}) ` and ` `type({"Luke"}) `   `  , everything shows as set ,

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use a `try-excep` expression in order to find out whether your name exist in the dictionary or not. If it exist there you can then return all the values of the respective value:

```
def get_nested_item(tree, check_on):
    try:
        sub_dict = tree[check_on]
    except KeyError:
        print("No result")
        return
    else:
        return sub_dict.values()
```

Also note that about checking the existence of your name in dictionary what you're ding here is a membership checking at following line:

```
if check_con in fi_name:
```

Which will not check for equality but checks if `check_con` appears within the dictionary keys. However if this is what you want you have to loop over your items and find the intended one. But also note that this may have multiple answers or in other words there may be multiple keys matching your criteria which contradicts with the whole purpose of using a dictionary.

Demo:

```
In [11]: get_nested_item(tree, "George")
Out[11]: dict_values([{'Mickey'}])

In [12]: get_nested_item(tree, "Luke")
Out[12]: dict_values([{'The Chancellor'}])

In [13]: get_nested_item(tree, "Sarah")
No result
```

Comment: @Karamzov What was your input?

Answer (score 1):

this is a variant where i use `next(iter(...))` in order to get the 'first' element of your `dict` and `set` (note that you innermost curly brackets in your `tree` are `set`s and not `dict`s):

```
def get(tree, name):

    def first(seq):
        return next(iter(seq))

    if name in tree:
        return first(first(tree[name].values()))
    else:
        return None

print(get(tree=tree, name='Juan'))  # 'Thompson'
print(get(tree=tree, name='Jan'))   # None
```

as both `set`s and `dict_values` (which is the type `dict(...).values()` returns) are not indexable (have no `__getitem__` method) i turn them into an iterator using [`iter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=iter#iter) and get the first element using [`next`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=built#next).

Comment: good one,  i didnt get the  function part well but its returning the result

Comment: what needs more explaining? the `first` function?

Comment: ~def first(seq):~